# Supporting recurring events across time zones and daylight savings changes

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc, dst

Built a basic system which allows a user to *Schedule a meeting with person A, B, C on some date/time*.

I wanted to sanity check that our solution will work across DST changes.

The two key classes are:

- `User` - holds the user's `ZoneId` so `Europe/Paris`, `Asia/Tokyo` etc.
- `Event` - holds the `LocalDateTime` of the scheduled event  eg. `2018-05-04T10:00:00.000` and the `ZoneId` of the user at the time of the event's creation eg. `Europe/Paris`.

We then stick the event in our scheduler:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyScheduler {

    private final TaskScheduler executor;

    ...

    public void schedule(Event event) {
        ...
        ZonedDateTime scheduledAt = ZonedDateTime.of(event.getScheduledAt(), event.getScheduledAtTimeZone());
        if (scheduledAt.isAfter(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))) {
            executor.schedule(task, Date.from(scheduledAt.toInstant()));
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm correct the above code should start the event set for Friday 10am `Europe/Paris` no matter whether the clocks are UTC+1 or UTC+2.

Does the above approach seem sane?

I've also noticed that the `ZonedDateTime` class holds an offset in addition to the time and zone eg. `2018-05-02T20:46:03.002+01:00[Europe/London]`. The only reason (I can think of) to hold the offset would be to know whether the user created the event during daylight savings or not.

That being the case is there any benefit to our system storing the offset or are we good with just the local event time and the zone it was created in?

Answer (score 1):

The only real issue I can think of is the corner case where the event happens in the autumn when the clock is moved backward, then the `LocalDateTime` may be ambiguous even knowing the zone.

`Instant` is generally recommended for time-zone neutral points in time, so unless it’s a strict requirement to know the time-zone in which the event was created, I would use this. Also even if that *is* a requirement since you can still keep the `ZoneId` beside it. It would also make your code a bit simpler. The other sane option is a `ZonedDateTime` for the scheduled time; it appeals less to me.